# mat datepicker regex pattern

Tags: angular, regex, typescript

I am having some issue figuring out where exactly am I going awry with my date regex. Issue is that with mat dateinput you pretty much input a very long date and QA dislikes this (i.e: 1/1/2022222)

Valid dates would of course have to be in either of these two formats: 01/01/0000 or 1/1/0000

I've added a RegEx as so:

```
let dateRegex = new RegExp("/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}")

this.coachFilterSearchForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        Companies: [''],
        Coaches: [''],
        FirstName: [''],
        LastName: [''],
        Email: [''],
        MobileNumber: [''],
        DateOfBirthObject: ['', Validators.pattern(dateRegex)],
        AccountStatuses: [accountStatusDefaultValue]
      }
    )
```

and I've verified that it is valid using https://regex101.com/ however when running the date input is shown as false regardless of what I've inputted (date picker selection value, manually inputting it). Where exactly am I missing the obvious (other than regex being cancer)?

Comment: Maybe you are managing it as digits, and dateinput is in string or date format?

Comment: @JuanVicenteBerzosaTejero that is what I am thinking, so instead I thought of tapping into the dateChange/dateInput event of the date picker. Alas, it appears to refuse to fire completely

Comment: nvm i was dumb and i applied to the wrong filter (we have tow similar filters on the same page depending on if a particular toggle is on or not)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by tapping into the date change and date input events of the date picker object and then testing the regex against that. As Juan suggested, odds are it is because the underlying value of the picker was a full date.

Note the case where we check for if the `rawDate` that is the date from the event is null (that is to say either empty or invalid - 01/130/2022). This is necessary to make sure we handle the situation where a user may have had inputs and then cleared it out

```
addEvent(event: any) {
    let rawDate = event.value;
    let formDateValue = this.coachFilterSearchForm.controls["DateOfBirthObject"];

    if(rawDate == null && formDateValue.invalid) {
      this.coachFilterSearchForm.controls["DateOfBirthObject"].setErrors({"incorrect" : true});
      return;
    }

    let formattedDate = formatDate(rawDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'en-US');

    this.validateDate(formattedDate);
  }

  validateDate(result: string) {
    let dateRegex = new RegExp(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/)
    let valid = dateRegex.test(result);

    if(!valid)
      this.coachFilterSearchForm.controls["DateOfBirthObject"].setErrors({"incorrect" : true});
    else
      this.coachFilterSearchForm.controls["DateOfBirthObject"].setErrors(null);

  }

<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                    <mat-label>Date of Birth</mat-label>
                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="DateOfBirthObject" placeholder="M/D/YY" 
                      (dateInput)="addEvent($event)"
                      (dateChange)="addEvent($event)"/>
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
                  </mat-form-field>
```

Edit:

Another approach that is more maintainable and also more reusable is to convert this into a custom validator.

Steps:

1. Create a new TS file, name it something relevant like "custom-validators.ts"
2. Convert above code into a stand alone function that can be exported:

   export function dateValidator(regExp : RegExp) : ValidatorFn {
   return (c : AbstractControl) : ValidationErrors => {
   return validateDateControl(c);
   }

   function validateDateControl(control: AbstractControl) : ValidationErrors {
   let rawDate = control.value;

   ```
   if(rawDate === "") {
     return;
   }

   if(rawDate == null && control.invalid) {
     return { "incorrect": true};
   }

   let formattedDate = formatDate(rawDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy', 'en-US');

   return validateDate(formattedDate, control, regExp);
   ```

   }

   function validateDate(result: string, control : AbstractControl, dateRegex : RegExp) : ValidationErrors {
   let valid = dateRegex.test(result);

   ```
   if(!valid)
     return { "incorrect": true};
   else
    return null;
   ```

   }
   }
3. Leverage it within your form definition and pass in the new custom
   validator:

```
let dateRegex = new RegExp(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/)

    this.coachFilterSearchForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        //array {value: entity id, name: "entity name"}
        Companies: [''],
        //array {value: coach id, name: "coach name"}
        Coaches: [''],
        FirstName: [''],
        LastName: [''],
        Email: [''],
        MobileNumber: [''],
        DateOfBirthObject: ['', [dateValidator(dateRegex)]],
        AccountStatuses: [accountStatusDefaultValue]
      }
    )
```